# With alexandria, how to include an external framework in the iOS app?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

With Delphi 11 Alexandria, how to include an external iOS framework in the app (for example, Facebook)?

Especially, how to tell Alexandria to sign the library before deploying it?

[RSP-22899: IOS: distributed dynamic library must be signed before to be deployed](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22899)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using 3rd party framework for IOS in Delphi Firemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475512/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree, but I want here to focus on signing the library that the other questions didn't ask